# Process all elements in map based on multiple conditions

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, c++17

I have the following data structure:

```
struct Data
{
    int p1;
    int p2;
    int p3;
    int size;
};
```

I need to sum size of all elements in map based on p1, p2 and p3 parameters. Here is an example code:

```
std::unordered_map<int, Data> m;
m[1] = Data{ 11, 22, 33, 10 };
m[2] = Data{ 33, 22, 11, 15 };
m[3] = Data{ 55, 55, 55, 25 };

int p1 = -1, p2 = 22, p3 = -1;
int size = 0;

for(const auto [key, data]: m)
{
    if ((p1 >= 0) && (p2 >= 0) && (p3 >= 0)) 
    {
        if ((p1 == data.p1) && (p2 == data.p2) && (p3 == data.p3))
        {
            size += data.size;
        }
    }
    else if ((p1 >= 0) && (p2 >= 0) && (p3 < 0)) 
    {
        if ((p1 == data.p1) && (p2 == data.p2))
        {
            size += data.size;
        }
    }
    else if ((p1 >= 0) && (p2 < 0) && (p3 >= 0)) 
    {
        if ((p1 == data.p1) && (p3 == data.p3))
        {
            size += data.size;
        }
    }
    else if ((p1 < 0) && (p2 >= 0) && (p3 >= 0)) 
    {
        if ((p2 == data.p2) && (p3 == data.p3))
        {
            size += data.size;
        }
    }
    else if ((p1 < 0) && (p2 < 0) && (p3 >= 0))
    {
        if (p3 == data.p3)
        {
            size += data.size;
        }
    }
    else if ((p1 < 0) && (p2 >= 0) && (p3 < 0)) 
    {
        if (p2 == data.p2)
        {
            size += data.size;
        }
    }
    else if ((p1 >= 0) && (p2 < 0) && (p3 < 0)) 
    {
        if (p1 == data.p1)
        {
            size += data.size;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        size += data.size;
    }
}
```

As you can see map items are matched based on `p1`, `p2` and `p3` values. The `size` sum equals 25 for the above parameters. Is it possible to simplify that code using c++17/stl features ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can highly simplify your for range loop as follows

```
   for ( auto const & [key, data] : m )
      if (    ((p1 < 0) || (p1 == data.p1))
           && ((p2 < 0) || (p2 == data.p2))
           && ((p3 < 0) || (p3 == data.p3)) )
         size += data.size;
```

If you prefer, you can use `std::for_each()`, including `<algorithm>`

```
   std::for_each(m.cbegin(), m.cend(), [&](auto const & p)
    { if (    ((p1 < 0) || (p1 == p.second.p1))
           && ((p2 < 0) || (p2 == p.second.p2))
           && ((p3 < 0) || (p3 == p.second.p3)) )
         size += p.second.size; });
```

but I don't see advantages over the preceding solution.